# Grouping values inside of a dict of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

**Scenario:** I have one dict of Dataframes. Each of those Dataframes contains the data for one year (2017 to 2022). They have each two columns, the Code and the Value (where the value column name is simply the year of that given Dataframe).

**Input Data Sample:**

```
Code    2017
33200   6957
33200   151906
33200   142025
33200   729494
33200   68842
32420   153499
32320   1756310
32320   33949
32310   81860
32310   56127
32200   165520
```

Each of the Dataframes has the same list of codes, only difference is the year.

**Expected output:**

```
Code    2017
33200   1099224
32420   153499
32320   1790259
32310   137987
32200   165520
```

**Objective:** I am trying to do a groupby code to sum each value for that given code (similar to an SUMIF).

**Issue:** When I run the code below, the output dictionary is exactly the same as the input.

**Code:**

```
year_list_1 = [2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022]
sales_dict_2={}
for year_var in year_list_1:
    sales_dict_2[year_var] = sales_dict[year_var].groupby('Code',as_index=False)[[year_var]].sum() # where sales_dict is the dictionary mentioned above
```

**Question:** Why is this code outputting the same DF as the input DF?

Comment: Are you logging `sales_dict_2` and not `sales_dict`?

Comment: @TheMaster What do you mean by logging?

Comment: `pd.concat` dataframes from dictionary and groupby the concatenated dataframe.

Comment: Could you explain please what do you mean by the _sum of each value for the given code_? Since you are showing data with unique values in the "Code" column, this sounds somewhat ambiguous in the context of the posted code.

Comment: @Vitalizzare It is basically a sum if. E.g. If I have a given code AAA appear 5 times, I wan to group it by summing the value of each AAA entry. In the end I will have one AAA entry, with the sum.

Comment: Okay, so how do you know that you have any problems with your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking the wrong way. It's better to work in this case with one data frame where `"Code"` is set as an index and values by year are columns. Then the total sum by code is just `data.sum(axis='columns')`:

```
years = range(2017, 2023)
df = pd.concat([df.set_index('Code') for df in sales_dict.values()],
               axis='columns')
total_sales = (
    df.sum('columns')
    .rename('Total')
    .reset_index()
)
```

*P.S.*
But maybe I incorrectly interpreted your words. What if your intention was not to sum each value for the given code along the years, but aggregate values in each frame by codes? Then your code looks correct, nothing wrong with it, and the question should be closed. Check if `"Code"` values have duplicates in your frames like this:

```
has_duplicated_codes = {year: df['Code'].duplicated().any() 
                        for year, df in sales_dict.items()}
```

I guess that `any(has_duplicated_codes.values()) == False` on your data.

---

But suppose we have these data with duplicated different codes:

```
sales = {
    (y:=2020): pd.DataFrame({'Code': (c:=[*'ABCDAC']), y:[*range(1,len(c)+1)]}),
    (y:=2021): pd.DataFrame({'Code': (c:=[*'BCCAF']),  y:[*range(1,len(c)+1)]}),
    (y:=2022): pd.DataFrame({'Code': (c:=[*'AACA']),   y:[*range(1,len(c)+1)]}),
}
```

To combine them in a single frame we can use slightly modified code from the original post:

```
df = pd.concat([df.set_index('Code').groupby(level=0).sum()
                for df in sales.values()], axis=1)
```

with these final data in `df`:

```
      2020  2021  2022
Code                  
A      6.0   4.0   7.0
B      2.0   1.0   NaN
C      9.0   5.0   3.0
D      4.0   NaN   NaN
F      NaN   5.0   NaN
```

Comment: I am trying to do an operation such as a sumif. E.g. A code AAA appears 5 times. I want to have only one AAA entry, with the value sum of those 5 entries. Indeed I tried to just create one single dataframe with each ear as a new column, and that works in this case as the codes are identical. The issue is, for code stability, if the codes change from year to year at some point, I assume that might create an issue. So I tried to do a dict to dict approach

Comment: @DGMS89  imo it would be helpful to provide not only the data but also the expected result on those data.

Comment: I am adding that now.